# Sending html2pdf generated pdf back to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data

I have to send a PDF generated on the client side using the `html2pdf` to a server. I have managed to convert the generated PDF to base64 and want to send it back using `axios`. Here is my client side code:

```
  function myFunction(){
           var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
           html2pdf().from(element).outputPdf().then(function(pdf) {
    //Convert to base 64
            const newpdf=btoa(pdf);
            console.log(newpdf)
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("uploadedFile", newpdf);
            axios.post('/upload',formData).then(res => { console.log(res) }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
    });
```

Here is my server side code:

```
app.post('/upload', fileUpload(), function(req, res) {  
  const sampleFile = req.files.uploadedFile;
  // do something with file
  res.send('File uploaded');
})
```

I think the problem is in client side as I get the base64 version of my converted pdf on my console but after that I get the error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: check in server side if you are able to receive the base64 encoded file

Comment: In the server side I get
**Cannot read property 'uploadedFile' of null**

Answer (score 0):

For the FormData in `express` you should use a middleware such [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

and you code will be like this :

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/upload', upload.single('uploadedFile'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```